# How to pass user's data from LoginController to my UserController

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-6

I want to return `User`s data after registering to `UserController` through `LoginController.`

Below is the `LoginController,` I have modified the default email login with student's index number:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends BaseController {

    public function username()
    {
        return 'index_no';
    }

    public function redirectTo(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->input('id');

        return redirect()->route('users', ['id' => $id]);
    }
}
```

While redirecting I want the users `id`, but I get this:

> FatalThrowableError error Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::redirectTo()

Comment: if you want to use any data of logged user you can use it simply by `auth()->user()->id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining an argument for the `redirectTo()` function that, by default, expects no params. Try this instead:

```
public function redirectTo()
{
    return redirect()->route('users', ['id' => auth()->id()]);
}
```

The explanation is, given the fact that this redirect will happen after a successfull login, the user is already logged in, so you are able to use the `Auth` facade or `auth()` helper to retrieve the info of the logged in user.

Comment: i got an error " Route [users] not defined "    this is the route i used   Route::get('users/{id}', 'UserController@show')->name('auth.clearance');

Comment: i have used php artisan route:cache, i still get the same results

Comment: If your route has that name, do this instead: `redirect()->route('auth.clearance', ['id' => auth()->id()]);`

Answer (score 0):

i just needed to eliminate the redirect() method

```
public function redirectTo()
{

    return route('auth.clearance',['id'=>auth()->id()]);
}
```